# Invalid block tag on line 140: 'wagtailuserbar'. Did you forget to register or load this tag? Wagtail error

Tags: python-3.x, django, wagtail

I am new to wagtail and I am not able to figure out why I am getting this error: Invalid block tag on line 140: 'wagtailuserbar'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?.

I am attaching the needful code.

--base.html--

```
    {% load static from static %}
    
    
    <!doctype html>

<html lang="en">


















  <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>
            {% block title %}
                   Title
                {% if self.seo_title %}{{ self.seo_title }}{% else %}{{ self.title }}{% endif %}
            {% endblock %}
            {% block title_suffix %}
                {% with self.get_site.site_name as site_name %}
                    {% if site_name %}- {{ site_name }}{% endif %}
                {% endwith %}
            {% endblock %}
        </title>
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

        {# Global stylesheets #}
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/mysite_blog.css' %}">

        {% block extra_css %}
            {# Override this in templates to add extra stylesheets #}
        {% endblock %}

      {% block head %}
      {% endblock head %}





  <style>  </style>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </head>

    <body class="{% block body_class %}{% endblock %}">

        {% wagtailuserbar %}

        {% block content %}{% endblock %}

        {# Global javascript #}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/mysite_blog.js' %}"></script>

        {% block extra_js %}
            {# Override this in templates to add extra javascript #}
        {% endblock %}
    

<!-- Other Stuff -->

    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    


  </body>
</html>
```

a similar error occurred for {% static %} tag but was fixed by the 1st line in the above code. Please Help me with a solution to this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load both tags in the same `load` statement like this:

`{% load static wagtailuserbar %}`

`from static` is not needed.

Comment: That Works Perfectly. Thanks a lot for your help.